# How to use register in a script without side effect?

Tags: vimscript, register

I want to create a function like this:

```
function Foo()
    copy something from buffer into a register
    do something
    restore register
endfunction
```

`Foo` must have no side effect, every register should remain the same after you call it, how should i do it?

**Attempt**

**unnamed register**

```
function Foo()
    let [regText, regType] = [getreg('"'), getregtype('"')]
    norm! y{motion}
    do something
    call setreg('"', regText, regType)
endfunction
```

side effect:

- register 0 was changed
- if `'clipboard'` includes `unnamed` or `unnamedplus`, regster `*` or `+` was also changed.
- if `"` point to other register before calling `Foo`, it stopped pointing to it after the calling.

**named register**

```
function Foo()
    let [regText, regType] = [getreg('a'), getregtype('a')]
    norm! "ay{motion}
    do something
    call setreg('a', regText, regType)
endfunction
```

side effect:

- `"` now point to `a`.

**explicit unnamed register**

```
function Foo()
    let [regText, regType] = [getreg('"'), getregtype('"')]
    norm! ""y{motion}
    do something
    call setreg('"', regText, regType)
endfunction
```

side effect:

- if `"` point to other register before calling `Foo`, it stopped pointing to it after the calling.
- **update** register 0 was changed.

Comment: Why do you want to both copy a value in a register and restore the register to the original value in the same function? Would copying the in a variable work instead?

Comment: It's convenient to copy something from buffer into a register first.

Comment: ok, and the issue here is that `"ay{motion}` sets in the `"` (unnamed register) as well as `a`?

Comment: No, it set `"` point to `a`, check `:h quotequote`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your Vim contains the patch [8.2.0924](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0924), then try to use `getreginfo()`:

```
function Foo()
    let save_cb = &cb
    let regInfo = getreginfo('"')
    try
        norm! y{motion}
        do something
    finally
        let &cb = save_cb
        call setreg('"', regInfo)
    endtry
endfunction
```

The latter function returns a dictionary providing [all the info you need](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2345#issuecomment-647796660) to save and restore the unnamed register:

- its contents as a list (which allows you to not lose NULs) via the `regcontents` key
- its type via the `regtype` key
- the name of the register it points to via the `points_to` key

`getreginfo()` is the only way to restore the register to which the unnamed register pointed to originally.

You can test it like this:

```
vim -es -Nu NONE -i NONE -S <(cat <<'EOF'
    call setline(1, ['yanked text', 'deleted text', 'line deleted by mapping'])
    norm! yyjdd
    pu=['registers before mapping'] + [execute('reg \"01')]

    nno cd :call Func()<cr>
    fu Func()
        let save = getreginfo('"')
        norm! 2Gdd
        call setreg('"', save)
    endfu

    au VimEnter * call feedkeys('cd', 'xt')
        \ | $pu=['', 'registers after mapping'] + [execute('reg \"01')]
        \ | exe 'g/^registers/t.|norm! Vr='
        \ | 2,$p | qa!
EOF
)

registers before mapping
========================

Type Name Content
  l  ""   deleted text^J
  l  "0   yanked text^J
  l  "1   deleted text^J

registers after mapping
=======================

Type Name Content
  l  ""   deleted text^J
  l  "0   yanked text^J
  l  "1   deleted text^J
```

---

Note that if your Vim doesn't support `getreginfo()`, you should ask `getreg()` to give you the contents of a register as a list instead of a string, by passing it a third non-zero argument:

```
let [regText, regType] = [getreg('"'), getregtype('"')]
                          ^---------^
                               ✘

let [regText, regType] = [getreg('"', 1, 1), getregtype('"')]
                          ^---------------^
                                  ✔
```

That's the only way to correctly handle possible NULs.  See `:h getreg()`:

> If {list} is present and |TRUE|, the result type is changed
> to |List|. Each list item is one text line. Use it if you care
> about zero bytes possibly present inside register: without
> third argument both NLs and zero bytes are represented as NLs
> (see |NL-used-for-Nul|).

---

I don't think you need to temporarily remove the `y` flag from `'cpo'`.  The dot command keeps its original behavior after your function is finished:

```
set cpo+=y
norm! dd
fu Func()
    norm! yy
endfu
call Func()
norm! .
" dot keeps removing the current line
```

See `:h function-search-undo`.

As for the dot register, it contains the last inserted text (see `:h quote_.`).  But a yank does not insert any text, so it can't alter the register, regardless of whether `y` is in `'cpo'`.  And even if it did, [it would probably not matter](https://github.com/lacygoill/wiki/blob/master/vim/register.md#what-about-the-dot-register--is-it-restored).

Answer (score 5):

You've identified most of the issues - I think the best one can do is using the unnamed register, saving its contents and type, and temporarily resetting `'clipboard'` and [`:help cpo-y`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#cpo-y) for yanks. I don't think it's possible to avoid the aliasing of register 0, but as these numbered registers are ephemeral and therefore rarely used, it's not so bad.

Here's the implementation of [`ingo#register#KeepRegisterExecuteOrFunc()`](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library/blob/e7cc1815df2c160b4cb4fd804c22ae7b1977c640/autoload/ingo/register.vim#L32-L64) from my [ingo-library plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433).

```
function! ingo#register#KeepRegisterExecuteOrFunc( Action, ... )
"******************************************************************************
"* PURPOSE:
"   Commands in the executed a:Action do not modify the default register.
"* ASSUMPTIONS / PRECONDITIONS:
"   None.
"* EFFECTS / POSTCONDITIONS:
"   None.
"* INPUTS:
"   a:Action    Either a Funcref or Ex commands to be :executed.
"   a:arguments Value(s) to be passed to the a:Action Funcref (but not the
"       Ex commands).
"* RETURN VALUES:
"   Result of evaluating a:Action, for Ex commands you need to use :return.
"******************************************************************************
    let l:save_clipboard = &clipboard
    set clipboard= " Avoid clobbering the selection and clipboard registers.
    if stridx(&cpoptions, 'y') != -1
        let l:save_cpoptions = &cpoptions
        set cpoptions-=y
    endif
    let l:save_reg = getreg('"')
    let l:save_regmode = getregtype('"')
    try
        return call('ingo#actions#ExecuteOrFunc', [a:Action] + a:000)
    finally
        call setreg('"', l:save_reg, l:save_regmode)
        if exists('l:save_cpoptions')
            let &cpoptions = l:save_cpoptions
        endif
        let &clipboard = l:save_clipboard
    endtry
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

I came looking for copper and found gold!!

Excellent previous answers helped to code what I aimed, alike (but not the same) as questioned:

- A: modify a register in command line
- B: copy one register into other

A:

```
nnoremap @@a <Esc>:let @a="<C-r>a"<Left>
nnoremap @@b <Esc>:let @b="<C-r>b"<Left>
" etc
nnoremap @@z <Esc>:let @z="<C-r>z"<Left>
```

B:

```
fun! CopyRegister(reg_origin,reg_destiny)
    let [regText, regType] = [getreg(a:reg_origin, 1, 1), getregtype(a:reg_origin)]
    call setreg(a:reg_destiny, l:regText, l:regType)
    echo "Register '" a:reg_destiny "' changed to value of register'" a:reg_origin "': " l:regText
endfun
nnoremap @@ab :call CopyRegister('a','b')<cr>
nnoremap @@ac :call CopyRegister('a','c')<cr>
" etc.
nnoremap @@zw :call CopyRegister('z','w')<cr>
```